# Joining two tables results in a connection failure to the server in psql and pgAdmin4

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, pgadmin-4

I am currently practicing SQL on an IMDB dataset, and here's the strange thing that I encounter.

PgAdmin4 and psql always raise an error telling me:

> Connection to the server has been lost

... or ...:

> Server closed the connection unexpectedly

... whenever I try to join two tables in the dataset using a query like:

```
select * 
from movie, movie_directors 
where movie.id = movie_directors.mid
```

However, simple queries like:

```
select * from movie
```

... or ...:

```
select count(*) from movie_directors
```

.. work just fine.

Nevertheless, joining tables does not raise such error when I do query on some small test dataset I created.

Can somebody please help me fix this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check your server's log for errors, sounds like something is crashing

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the inner join version:

```
select * 
from movie inner join movie_directors 
on movie.id = movie_directors.mid
```